# Using generic animations with different weapons in Unity/Blender

Tags: unity, animation, blender

Working on a game in which players can upgrade their weapons. I've animated a character to hold a weapon, but I don't want to create a unique animation for each weapon. How do I create a relationship between any weapon and the character such that it's simple to switch weapons in Unity?

I'd like to make one generic animation for all of my swords and be able to just replace the sword model in Unity when the player decides to switch weapons.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! What's the final result you're trying to achieve? Do you want to adapt the same animation to different weapons sharing a similar layout (e.g. two-handed guns)? Or, are you trying to implement a functionality that replaces the currently visible weapon with the side one back and forth, as seen in common shooters?

Comment: @liggiorgio Hi! I'd like to make one generic animation for all of my swords and be able to just replace the sword model in Unity when the player decides to switch weapons.

Comment: Nice, this is useful information to include in your original question. This way, others will understand your issue at a glance with no need to read through comments.